# Problem with component on another user

Tags: lightning-web-components, permissions

I have problem like: i cant see my Lwc component on another user.

**LWC component on Admin**
[image]

**LWC component on another user**
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<classAccesses>
        <apexClass>StockMarketSharesController</apexClass>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
```

have it i just manualy added permset to apex class

Comment: Did this solve your problem, or did you mean to inlcude these details in your question?